# Take overall minus sign in front in dot product with symbolic variables

Tags: symbolic, dot

I have the following as the output of a calculation

```
a.b+(-a).b
```

and I would like Mathematica to evaluate this to zero. Is there a way to specify that for my purposes `(-a).b` is the same as `-(a.b)`?

---

(I've been searching for a solution and tried a number of things but thought it would be better to keep my question clear and concise not to distract with irrelevant descriptions of my attempts solving it.)

Comment: Try `TensorExpand[a . b + (-a) . b]` and report back.

Comment: That solves it! Thank you very much. If you want you can submit it as an answer such that I can accept it.

Comment: Another way around: `(a.b + (-a).b) /. (-x_).y_ :> -x.y` returns zero.

Comment: Thank you for this alternative, it also works well for my purposes. But could you tell me why you use the `:>` operator and not the `->` operator in the `ReplaceAll` command? The normal arrow also works for this example. I see that in the documentation they moslty use the normal arrow and sometimes the colon-arrow, though without explanation. It seems that the colon version is more used to replace patterns and normal arrow to replace symbols, but this is also not generally true.